# Spring @Required Annotation deprecated?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, javabeans

I am trying to add `@Required` Annotation to my bean but complier says it's deprecated.

```java
public class Product {
    private String id;
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Required
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Is there a different annotation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [**documentation**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Required.html):

> Deprecated as of 5.1, in favor of **using constructor injection for required settings** (or a custom [`InitializingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) implementation).

```java
public class Product {
   private String id;

   public Product(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getId() {
      return id;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `@Autowired`.

```
@Autowired
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best answer i got is this :

```
@Autowired(required = true)
private String yourVariable;
```

if you set it required to false your String value will be null and you won't get an error

if you just typed @Autowired, then it is required = true by default,
try these to understand and read console error messages